# wso2 apimanager Active-Active deployment

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I have deploy API manager 4.0.0 All-in-one on 2 VMs,  front the system with a load balancer.
When one node shutdown by command "sh api-manager.sh stop", another swithes success and  runs well , but there are some error in console like below:

```
    TID: [-1] [] [2022-03-14 10:14:13,270] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker} - Error while trying to connect 
to the endpoint. Cannot borrow client for ssl://10.32.73.10:9711 org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://10.32.73.10:9711        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:147)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.run(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:59)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointException: Error while opening socket to 10.32.73.10:9711. Connection refused (Conne
ction refused)        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.java:75)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.client.AbstractClientPoolFactory.makeObject(AbstractClientPoolFactory.java:39)
        at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericKeyedObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericKeyedObjectPool.java:1212)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointConnectionWorker.connect(DataEndpointConnectionWorker.java:137)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:476)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:218)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:394)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:606)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:287)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:146)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.binary.BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.createClient(BinarySecureClientPoolFactory.java:58)
        ... 9 more

TID: [-1] [] [2022-03-14 10:14:15,158]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.endpoint.DataEndpointGroup} - No receiver is reachable at URL Endpoint/
Endpoints [tcp://10.32.73.10:9611], will try to reconnect every 30 sec
```

Are there anything wrong in the deployment.toml?

Answer (score 0):

In APIM active-active setup, each node is publishing throttling data to itself and to the other node. When you stop the other node, it can't publish the throttling data to the other node. Hence you see connection refused errors and this is expected. No harm having these error logs. It will recover when the other node is started. If you look at the deployment.toml, can find the other node details under the throttling configurations.